# How to create MySQL Table with no Insert allowed

Tags: mysql

In MySQL i need a table that stores only one static value, which the application can access and change if needed. For this purpose i have to make sure there can't be another row inserted.

So i need to create a table that allows update operations, but no insert and no delete operations. 
Is there another way than checking the size of the table in a trigger and if > 1 cancel the operation?

Comment: how can you change anything if you dont want update or insert?

Comment: update should be allowed, only inserts and deletes not

Comment: If you've already know the exact number of records of the table then you can simple do a query to check the count, and if it returns more than the predefined numbers then cancel the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Stephan a possible Solution is by creating another User and specifying such privileges that rows from that table can't be inserted or deleted. I think it's a good solution but since I'm accessing multiple tables via the existing user and i didn't wanted to create another one, i solved the problem with two triggers.

So here's my solution:

Trigger: On_Insert_Check_Count

```
BEGIN

IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oe_last_tabkey) >= 1) THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "DIE: Only Update allowed on this table.";
END IF;

END
```

Trigger: On_Delete

```
BEGIN

SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "DIE: Only Update allowed on this table.";

END
```

With this solution, everytime any User tries to insert (as long as there is min 1 row existant) or to delete, MySQL will cancel the Operation with the Message: "DIE: Only Update allowed on this table".

Answer (score 1):

This can be controlled by specifying the desired privileges for the mysql user used to interogate the table .

For example you can create the table and insert the values (for one time) with one user then use another user that has only update privileges.

You can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)